# Copy all data from one mysql rds database to an other existing mysql rds db

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have two Mysql RDS databases in the same region and account. I wanted to copy a full data from one db to another. I've tried to look into AWS's documentation on how to do this but it takes me to the process of taking a snapshot and create a new one from the snapshot but I still want to persist the data in db #2(destination db).

Comment: makr a mysq2ldump and import it see the manual

Comment: use AWS DMS service to migrate across various AWS services and also if needed from on-prem

Comment: wouldn't AWS DMS move my data instead of copying(cloning) it?